# Correct way of extracting indices and values of non-NaN elements in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, find, nan

I have a data array with numbers and NaN elements. I would like to get 3 vectors with the indices and the respective values of the non-NaN elements of this array.

Here is how I do it:

```
[x,y]=find(~isnan(A));
[~,~,z]=find(A(~isnan(A)));
```

Now, this is not optimal. First the size of `z` differs from the size of `x` and `y` (it is one element shorter, and I don't know which one has been omitted). Second, I'm sure it's possible to do both in one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the second `find` at all, just a little bit of logical indexing that you were already using:

```
% Example data
A = rand(5);
A(A>0.5) = NaN;

iA = ~isnan(A);
[x,y] = find(iA);
z = A(iA(:));
```

Comment: Thanks, on a more general note, do you or @chappjc have an idea why my code gives different output sizes? I use both pretty often, I wouldn't like to be missing something.

Comment: @Jigg: Yes. In your first call to `find` you input an array the same size/dimensions as `A`. In the second call to `find` you've performed some logical indexing on `A` and are only passing in a column vector that contains the non-NaN elements of `A`. If you look at my code you'll see that `z` is exactly what you've passed into the second `find`. In many cases logical indexing suffices and the Editor will often suggest that `find` isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `find` or `isnan` twice since you get the subscripts with the first command.  Apply them to get the values in `A`:

```
[ii,jj] = find(~isnan(A));
z = A(sub2ind(size(A),ii,jj))
```

If you are opposed to `sub2ind`, you can use `ii+(jj-1)*size(A,1)`.

In the event that you you do not need `ii` and `jj` later, you can just do `A(~isnan(A))` to get `z` (no `find` needed).